# Ubuntu 13.04 desktop is not showing

Tags: 13.04

Whenever i m trying to start my pc .its not possible to go to.the desktop ...it takes some time and shows initramfs. can anyone help me.

Comment: This problem and an answer is propably here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286284/system-no-longer-boots-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-initramfs-dev-mappe

Please report back if this is your problem and solution or add more information about what you are doing and experiencing.

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling ubuntu. Also it is recommended to do a clean install instead of upgrade if you have upgraded on the first place.
Also i hope your system meets ubuntu's system requirements as shown here ---> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Reinstallation should be the last option to consider. It may be the most simple solution if you do not use your PC, but if you do, you might want to keep your settings and maintainance to a minimum. Also not everyone enjoys the process of an ubuntu Installation.

Comment: Now it.s working. Please tell me how to play music. It is asking for some plugins. And one more thing is that how to run .exe files. Please help me.