# Encrypted LVM not booting since recent update

Tags: boot, encryption, lvm

i am using a fully encrypted LVM disk and running Ubuntu 17.10 Stable. Until recently it was working fine:

```
grub - decryption password input - boots to OS
```

Now it's:

```
grub - busy box "gave up waiting for root device"
```

I have tried both suggestions on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286284/system-no-longer-boots-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-initramfs-dev-mappe) page:

suggestion 1: "run cryptsetup from within busybox" did not work because cryptsetup is not a recognised command

suggestion 2: "boot from usb, manually decrypt/mount and run update-initramfs", did not show any issues, i was able to go through all steps without issues, but nothing seems to have changed after rebooting.
(note: i also confirmed (while in the chroot) that /etc/crypttab exists and it has an entry for sda5_crypt). also tried running update-grub.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like initramfs-tools do not include cryptsetup for some reason. Maybe try changing initramfs system. Follow suggestion 2 but instead of "run update-initramfs" try "apt install dracut"

Comment: i had to reinstall as i needed to travel with the laptop monday. will try and recreate the problem when i get back from travels though,